# Inner Exception: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.GetItemSummary'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please tell me why this Exception has occured (obviously it can't find something...) and how to fix it?

**CODE**

```
public IEnumerable GetList(GridMetadata metadata) {
     var entities = new EPMSEntities();
     var items = entities.GetItemSummary(metadata.ProjectId); 
     //return items.Select(item => new ItemSummaryModel() {
             //IdProjectEquipmentItem = item.IdProjectEquipmentItem,
             //IdMasterEquipmentItem = item.idMasterEquipmentItem
            //}
         }

public virtual ObjectResult<GetItemSummary_Result> GetItemSummary(Nullable<int> idProject)
  {
    var idProjectParameter = idProject.HasValue ?
    new ObjectParameter("IdProject", idProject) :
    new ObjectParameter("IdProject", typeof(int));        
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetItemSummary_Result>("GetItemSummary", idProjectParameter); //keep getting error at this point
  }
```

**model.edmx**

```
<FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="GetItemSummary" FunctionName="EPMSModel.Store.GetItemSummary">.....
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 . Microsoft.NET-Framework64 v4.0.30319. Having all the database credentials..

**ERROR :** 
I keep getting this error. *An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the **inner exception** for details.*
[image]

Comment: That stored procedure exists in your database?

Comment: @RubensFarias No, it doesn't. Any idea on how to get that back in?

Comment: @rb4bhushan Are you sure you typed the name of the stored procedure correctly? Is it the correct schema name? Its worth double checking. If the stored procedure did exist, the code would have executed succesfully

Comment: @rb4bhushan Did you physically checkif the stored procedure exists in the database?

Comment: `sp_helptext 'dbo.GetItemSummary'` doesn't give me anything...The _object 'dbo.GetItemSummary' does not exist in database_  . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to recreate the stored procedure.

Comment: ...my project is running perfectly fine now. `dbo.GetItemSummary`  sproc was misplaced or not copied ... thnkw  :)  geeks